# Entering values in a table through java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Got a table with below html structure

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" data-bind="foreach: CargoViewModel.PackageArray()">
    <tbody style="border-bottom: 1px solid black !important">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 19%; vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 20%; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="text" style="width: 85%;" data-bind="value: NoOfPkgs, hasFocus: NoOfPackagesFocus, event: { blur: OnNoOfPkgsChange }" onkeypress="return allowNumericOnly(event);" ondrop="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Numeric');" onpaste="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Numeric');" maxlength="5" placeholder="Packages">
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: top; width: 25%; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <div class="input-group" data-bind="singlePopup: { pkgtype: 'PkgType', pkgtypename: 'PkgTypeName', callback: $root.PkgTypePopup }">
                                    <input type="text" class="igPWCTextBox" data-bind="value: PkgTypeName, attr: { 'id': ($index() + 1) + '_txtPkgName' }, event: { blur: OnPkgsTypeChange.bind($data, 'CargoEdit') }, hasFocus: PkgTypeNameFocus" oncopy="return false" ondrag="return false" onpaste="return false" placeholder="Type" id="1_txtPkgName"><span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="butn" type="button" data-bind="attr: { 'id': ($index() + 1) + '_btnPkgType' }" tabindex="-1" id="1_btnPkgType"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="0" data-bind="checked: IsHazardous">
                                <a tabindex="-1" data-bind="attr: { 'title': HazardousIconTitle }" class="ui-icon icon-warning-sign red" style="font-size: 1.4em; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: middle;" href="#" title="DG"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="0" data-bind="checked: IsReefer">
                                <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-icon icon-asterisk blue" title="Temperature Controlled" style="font-size: 1.6em; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: middle;" href="#"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" style="vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="0" data-bind="checked: IsNonStackable"><span style="margin-right: 5px; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;" title="Non Stackable">NS</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 15%; vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 25%; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="text" style="width: 65%; text-align: right;" data-bind="value: PkgGrossPerPiece, event: { blur: OnPkgGrossPerPiece }" onkeypress="CheckDecimalNumber(event,this,IHDecimals.GrWt);" ondrop="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" onpaste="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" maxlength="9" placeholder="Per Piece">
                                <span style="margin-left: 2px;" data-bind="html: CargoViewModel.DisplayWeightUOM()">kg</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="text" style="width: 65%; text-align: right;" data-bind="value: PkgGrossWeight, event: { blur: OnPkgGrossWeightChange }, hasFocus: PkgGrossWeightFocus" onkeypress="CheckDecimalNumber(event,this,IHDecimals.GrWt);" ondrop="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" onpaste="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" maxlength="9" placeholder="Gross Weight">
                                <span style="margin-left: 2px;" data-bind="html: CargoViewModel.DisplayWeightUOM()">kg</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 17%; vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 10%; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="text" style="width: 78%; text-align: right;" data-bind="value: PkgLength, event: { blur: OnPkgLengthChange }" onkeypress="CheckDecimalNumber(event,this,IHDecimals.IHLWH);" ondrop="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" onpaste="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" maxlength="9" placeholder="L">
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 10%; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="text" style="width: 78%; text-align: right;" data-bind="value: PkgWidth, event: { blur: OnPkgWidthChange }" onkeypress="CheckDecimalNumber(event,this,IHDecimals.IHLWH);" ondrop="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" onpaste="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" maxlength="9" placeholder="W">
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 10%; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="text" style="width: 78%; text-align: right;" data-bind="value: PkgHeight, event: { blur: OnPkgHeightChange }" onkeypress="CheckDecimalNumber(event,this,IHDecimals.IHLWH);" ondrop="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" onpaste="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" maxlength="9" placeholder="H">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" style="vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="text" style="width: 65%; text-align: right;" data-bind="value: PkgVolume, event: { blur: OnPkgVolumeChange }, hasFocus: PkgVolumeFocus" onkeypress="allowNumbersafterDecimalPoint(event,this,IHDecimals.VolCBM);" ondrop="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" onpaste="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" maxlength="9" placeholder="Volume">
                                <span style="margin-left: 2px;" data-bind="html: CargoViewModel.DisplayVolumeUOM()">m<sup>3</sup></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 23%; vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                <textarea rows="3" title="Shipping Marks" style="width: 4.63cm; margin-top: 3px; height: 40px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; resize: none; padding: 1px;" data-bind="value: MarksandNos, event: { keyup: $parent.OnKeyupCargoInput.bind($data, 'PkgMarks'), mousedown: $parent.OnKeyupCargoInput.bind($data, 'PkgMarks'), paste: $parent.OnKeyupCargoInput.bind($data, 'PkgMarks'), change: OnChangeCargoInput.bind($data, 'PkgMarks') }" placeholder="Shipping Marks"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 27%; vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                <textarea title="Description" style="width: 5.51cm; margin-top: 3px; height: 40px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; resize: none; padding: 1px;" rows="3" data-bind="value: GoodsDescription, event: { keyup: $parent.OnKeyupCargoInput.bind($data, 'PkgDesc'), mousedown: $parent.OnKeyupCargoInput.bind($data, 'PkgDesc'), paste: $parent.OnKeyupCargoInput.bind($data, 'PkgDesc'), change: OnChangeCargoInput.bind($data, 'PkgDesc') }" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody style="border-bottom: 1px solid black !important">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 19%; vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 20%; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="text" style="width: 85%;" data-bind="value: NoOfPkgs, hasFocus: NoOfPackagesFocus, event: { blur: OnNoOfPkgsChange }" onkeypress="return allowNumericOnly(event);" ondrop="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Numeric');" onpaste="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Numeric');" maxlength="5" placeholder="Packages">
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: top; width: 25%; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <div class="input-group" data-bind="singlePopup: { pkgtype: 'PkgType', pkgtypename: 'PkgTypeName', callback: $root.PkgTypePopup }">
                                    <input type="text" class="igPWCTextBox" data-bind="value: PkgTypeName, attr: { 'id': ($index() + 1) + '_txtPkgName' }, event: { blur: OnPkgsTypeChange.bind($data, 'CargoEdit') }, hasFocus: PkgTypeNameFocus" oncopy="return false" ondrag="return false" onpaste="return false" placeholder="Type" id="2_txtPkgName"><span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="butn" type="button" data-bind="attr: { 'id': ($index() + 1) + '_btnPkgType' }" tabindex="-1" id="2_btnPkgType"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="0" data-bind="checked: IsHazardous">
                                <a tabindex="-1" data-bind="attr: { 'title': HazardousIconTitle }" class="ui-icon icon-warning-sign red" style="font-size: 1.4em; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: middle;" href="#" title="DG"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="0" data-bind="checked: IsReefer">
                                <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-icon icon-asterisk blue" title="Temperature Controlled" style="font-size: 1.6em; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: middle;" href="#"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" style="vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="0" data-bind="checked: IsNonStackable"><span style="margin-right: 5px; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;" title="Non Stackable">NS</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 15%; vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 25%; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="text" style="width: 65%; text-align: right;" data-bind="value: PkgGrossPerPiece, event: { blur: OnPkgGrossPerPiece }" onkeypress="CheckDecimalNumber(event,this,IHDecimals.GrWt);" ondrop="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" onpaste="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" maxlength="9" placeholder="Per Piece">
                                <span style="margin-left: 2px;" data-bind="html: CargoViewModel.DisplayWeightUOM()">kg</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="text" style="width: 65%; text-align: right;" data-bind="value: PkgGrossWeight, event: { blur: OnPkgGrossWeightChange }, hasFocus: PkgGrossWeightFocus" onkeypress="CheckDecimalNumber(event,this,IHDecimals.GrWt);" ondrop="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" onpaste="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" maxlength="9" placeholder="Gross Weight">
                                <span style="margin-left: 2px;" data-bind="html: CargoViewModel.DisplayWeightUOM()">kg</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 17%; vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 10%; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="text" style="width: 78%; text-align: right;" data-bind="value: PkgLength, event: { blur: OnPkgLengthChange }" onkeypress="CheckDecimalNumber(event,this,IHDecimals.IHLWH);" ondrop="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" onpaste="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" maxlength="9" placeholder="L">
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 10%; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="text" style="width: 78%; text-align: right;" data-bind="value: PkgWidth, event: { blur: OnPkgWidthChange }" onkeypress="CheckDecimalNumber(event,this,IHDecimals.IHLWH);" ondrop="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" onpaste="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" maxlength="9" placeholder="W">
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 10%; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="text" style="width: 78%; text-align: right;" data-bind="value: PkgHeight, event: { blur: OnPkgHeightChange }" onkeypress="CheckDecimalNumber(event,this,IHDecimals.IHLWH);" ondrop="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" onpaste="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" maxlength="9" placeholder="H">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" style="vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                                <input type="text" style="width: 65%; text-align: right;" data-bind="value: PkgVolume, event: { blur: OnPkgVolumeChange }, hasFocus: PkgVolumeFocus" onkeypress="allowNumbersafterDecimalPoint(event,this,IHDecimals.VolCBM);" ondrop="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" onpaste="AllowOnPaste(event,this,'Number');" maxlength="9" placeholder="Volume">
                                <span style="margin-left: 2px;" data-bind="html: CargoViewModel.DisplayVolumeUOM()">m<sup>3</sup></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 23%; vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                <textarea rows="3" title="Shipping Marks" style="width: 4.63cm; margin-top: 3px; height: 40px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; resize: none; padding: 1px;" data-bind="value: MarksandNos, event: { keyup: $parent.OnKeyupCargoInput.bind($data, 'PkgMarks'), mousedown: $parent.OnKeyupCargoInput.bind($data, 'PkgMarks'), paste: $parent.OnKeyupCargoInput.bind($data, 'PkgMarks'), change: OnChangeCargoInput.bind($data, 'PkgMarks') }" placeholder="Shipping Marks"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 27%; vertical-align: top; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
                <textarea title="Description" style="width: 5.51cm; margin-top: 3px; height: 40px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; resize: none; padding: 1px;" rows="3" data-bind="value: GoodsDescription, event: { keyup: $parent.OnKeyupCargoInput.bind($data, 'PkgDesc'), mousedown: $parent.OnKeyupCargoInput.bind($data, 'PkgDesc'), paste: $parent.OnKeyupCargoInput.bind($data, 'PkgDesc'), change: OnChangeCargoInput.bind($data, 'PkgDesc') }" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I send values (through sendkeys) into textboxes and checkboxes associated with each row. How to traverse through each row with in this table.

The rows can also be dynamically added but how can I send values to textboxes and select checkboxes with in this table structure

Trying to achieve this through Selenium Java

Comment: What did you try? can you post your code sample?

Comment: @Sureshmani Have been trying this and finally cracked this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code after hits and misses with the xpath(s) is working well.

```
List<WebElement> tbodyElements =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"divTemplatePkgDetails\"]/div[3]/table/tbody"));
        System.out.println(tbodyElements.size());
        
        for(int i=1; i<= tbodyElements.size(); i++)
        {
            String value=null;
            if(i%2 == 0)
            {
                value="Bag";
            }
            else if(i%2==1)
            {
                value="Pallet";
            }
            
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"divTemplatePkgDetails\"]/div[3]/table/tbody["+i+"]/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input")).sendKeys("10");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"divTemplatePkgDetails\"]/div[3]/table/tbody["+i+"]/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input")).sendKeys("100");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"divTemplatePkgDetails\"]/div[3]/table/tbody["+i+"]/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input")).sendKeys("200");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"divTemplatePkgDetails\"]/div[3]/table/tbody["+i+"]/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/input")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"divTemplatePkgDetails\"]/div[3]/table/tbody["+i+"]/tr/td[4]/textarea")).sendKeys("SM");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"divTemplatePkgDetails\"]/div[3]/table/tbody["+i+"]/tr/td[5]/textarea")).sendKeys("Description");
            driver.findElement(By.id(i+"_txtPkgName")).sendKeys(value);         
            Thread.sleep(2000);;
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//li[@class='active']//a)["+i+"]")).click();  
        }
```